# How to add characters in the results up to certain length in SQL

Tags: sql, character

I need to add * symbols to make all records to 15 digits.   What is the best way?

```
Ex:)
From
2345
32456674
543
5
467888

to 
2345***********
32456674*******
543************
5**************
467888*********
```

Thanks,

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your other questions are tagged for SQL Server, so I will assume that database.

SQL Server does not support `rpad()`, but you can use `left()` and `replicate()`:

```
select left(concat(col, replicate('*', 15)), 15)
```

or:

```
select left(col + replicate('*', 15), 15)
```

If `col` is not already a string, then you need to cast it to one.

Some databases have direct support for an `rpad()` function that does this directly.

Comment: Thanks!  but I have tried concat already then I get "'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name." error.   I am using SQL 2012.

Comment: @Julian . . . `concat()` was introduced in SQL Server 2012, so you should be able to use it.  You might need to check that your compatibility level is at least 110.

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT(col, (REPLICATE('*', (15-(LEN(col))))))
```

Concatenate `col` onto the set of *'s that is equal to the difference in value it takes for the `col` to reach 15 characters long. so for `col = 2345` you need 11 more chars to reach 15.

This evaluates to:

```
CONCAT(2345, (REPLICATE('*', (15-(4))))) = 2345***********
```

Check parentheses for correct closures

Answer (score 0):

This trick works with SQLite :)

```
SELECT
  col || substr(
    '........................................', -- string of N characters
    1,(N - length(col)) -- N is the number of characters
  ) AS "col"
```

In this example, N = 40.